# What shell allows recalling commands with certain beginning?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Programs like matlab/octave and I'm sure many other ones allow you to start typing a command, and then hit <kbd>Up</kbd> to recall the last command that starts with the typed characters.

Common linux shell `bash` doesnot do this. Is there a different shell that does?
I'm not asking how to find out the last command, I'm asking if there's a shell that's a little friendlier.

Comment: Not suggesting a different shell,  hence the comment instead of answer.  Have you tried the `Ctrl-r` reverse incremental search feature?  Alternatively, `!foo` will run the last command you entered beginning with `foo`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about `!` but if I want to run `!rm` then it gets creepy

Comment: Which is why I prefer `Ctrl-r` because you can interactively edit before hitting enter.  For a 2 step approach you can do `!rm:p` to just print the expansion without running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash does allow this when you have the following uncommented in `.inputrc`:

```
# alternate mappings for up/down arrows to search the history
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

Comment: This is wrong. It's not page up/down, but arrow up/down.

Comment: @Daniel: Oh yes, I forgot to change the comment after changing the keys, but it was only the comment which was wrong.

Comment: Thanks! On the side note, is there an actual shell that's better?

Comment: @Mikhail: That would be a subjective matter, but I have not used anything else on Linux apart from `iPython` and `bash` would not be so popular if there was something much better.  Some people seem to prefer `zsh`, but don't know much about it.

Comment: @Mikhail Use whichever is default (i.e. presumably widely used, well-tested and well-integrated), unless you have specific requirements only a different shell can (easily) solve.

Comment: @Mikhail That would be a subjective matter, and also zsh is better :D Among other, better completion, the tab key allows not only to complete but also to select the wanted argument among the list

Answer (score 3):

Bash actually does it, when you configure it to do so. Put this in `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

Then, *up* and *down* arrow keys will search through history using the prefix of the current command up to the cursor.

These functions are unbound by default. There are other history search commands, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the forward and reverse history search. From bash(1):

```
   reverse-search-history (C-r)
          Search  backward  starting  at  the current line and moving `up'
          through the  history  as  necessary.   This  is  an  incremental
          search.
   forward-search-history (C-s)
          Search  forward  starting  at the current line and moving `down'
          through the  history  as  necessary.   This  is  an  incremental
          search.
```

Just hit ^R and stat typing, it does exactly what you request. Press ^R multiple times to browse through the hits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are different shells that have this feature built-in. One such shell is called zsh (Z shell).

zsh has a feature called incremental history search which allows you to search through your command history by typing the first few characters of the command you want to recall and then pressing the Up arrow key. It will search through your history and show you the most recent command that starts with the characters you typed.

You can also use the Ctrl-R keybinding to search through your command history incrementally.

To use zsh, you will need to install it on your system. You can install it by running the following command on Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

After installation, you can switch to zsh by running:

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

You can enable it in bash as well, put the following 2 lines into your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

This will enable the incremental history search feature in bash, so that you can search through your command history by typing the first few characters of the command you want to recall and then pressing the Up arrow key.

Once you've added the lines to your .bashrc file, you can either log out and back in or run the command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You can also use other shells like fish, which also has similar features.

You can check it out, see if you like the features and decide if you want to use it as your primary shell.